# Android layouts - offsetting a background image in xml

Tags: android, layout, background, offset

I have a large png that I would like to use as a background on different layouts, but offset it so that I can have different parts showing (much like you can in CSS), preferable in the xml.

My main layout for the activity contains the following xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@layout/bg1">
```

Layout bg1 consists of the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/big_image"
android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
android:paddingTop="50sp"
android:gravity="top|left" />
```

The gravity property works as expected but margins and paddings are ignored, presumably because I'm working on a bitmap object rather than a layout. What I want to do is set these to a minus amount so that only part of the picture is shown. I've tried using a shape but that only wraps the content whereas I need to fill the entire background.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: Solved with the following, ensuring ImageView is at top of XML so that it is behind all other controls:
<ImageView android:id="@+id/bigLogo" android:src="@drawable/big_logo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="-90px" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used an ImageView with a negative top margin value. The ImageView is declared first within the layout so that it is lowest in the stack of controls and will be rendered behind the others.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bigLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/big_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
        android:layout_marginTop="-100px" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an InsetDrawable (it works from XML) to add extra padding to another drawable.

Comment: I have changed the layout of bg1.xml in my original post to use an inset with insetTop set. However, the entire contents of the layout is inset not just the background drawable. I was expecting the background to be treated as a 'watermark' like a web page and am surprised the main content is affected. Perhaps I should just use a positioned ImageView instead?